# How to check email already exist in register form in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I forget how to check email if it already exist one prompt will occur to alert user use another email instead of that in Access 2007

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head something like this

```
If isnull(dlookup(“EmailAddress”,”tblCustomers”,”EmailAddress=’test@test.com’”))=true then
    ‘open your not clash form
Else
    ‘open the clash form
End if
```

Comment: i need to check a list of emails in table customers, how can i do that?

Comment: Using the code above! What that is doing is trying to find the email address "test@test.com" in the table "tblCustomers" assuming that the field is called "EmailAddress". If it finds a record it will return it , or if if cant it will return null. From that logic you can then flow your program